# custom ui delegates for TreeUI

Tags: java, swing, path, jtree, uimanager

For some reason, my TreeUI doesn't get applied. I am using MetalTheme and want to customize the TreeUI. So, I started by copying the TreeUI code and renaming the class EzTreeUI. Am I doing this right ? None of the commands below work. When I debug and step over the statements below, `UIManager.getDefaults().get("TreeUI");` still returns `javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalTreeUI`.

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("TreeUI", EzTreeUI.class.getName());
UIManager.put("TreeUI", EzTreeUI.class.getName());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UIManager.put("TreeUI", "EzTreeUI");
```

Comment: @ShaggyInjun should be full_path, then same as for Class, Resources Icon (1mio times asked here)